# How to trigger a function when the iPhone is rotated 90 degrees?

Tags: iphone

How do I detect the rotation of the iPhone for approximately 90 degrees?  Additionally, I don't need/want the screen itself to rotate.  I just want to call a function when the phone has been rotated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your view controller will be sent:

```
  -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Implement it to do something when the phone is being rotated

After the rotation is done, you get:

```
  - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Here it is in the docs (see Handling View Rotations)

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate the device, your view controller receives a didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
message, with the old orientation. You can check the interfaceOrientation property to see the current rotation, and do something accordingly.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the events sent prior to ViewController rotation. Namely:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

and post rotation

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

Answer (score 1):

you should first implement the instance method "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" and return YES.
and then the two method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

The method names are correct... but they never get called.
What would cause that?